# Google Map USGSOverlay clickevent multi response on same level markers

Tags: javascript, android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I used Google Map V3 create 20 markers , click one marker and the marker will show it's infowindow (which the marker , the infowindow all create by USGSOverlay).

Now ,I get a bugs, example:

I clicked marker A,and show the infowindow B, here I will click infowindow B to goto another page,but now , the marker C (which is under infowindow B) also got the clickenvent ,and show it's infowindow D.

why? I try to stopPropagation,but nouse!

```
function makeInfoWindow(item){
    var marker= new USGSOverlay(getLargeView(item),item.getLatLng(),{x:-56,y:-118},'infobox',item.id);
    mGmap.addOverlay('infobox',marker);
    marker.bind("click",function(event){
        event.cancelBubble = true;
        if (event.stopPropagation) {
            event.stopPropagation();
        }
        console.log("InfoWindow click ");
    });
    return marker;
}

USGSOverlay.prototype.bind = function (eventname, callback) {
    this.clickListener=callback;
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(this.htmlObj_, eventname, this.clickListener);
}
```

I think the markers and infowindos at the same level , so they got the same clickevent, I spent a lot of time for this, any one help me ?

```
//marker
function makePointMarker(item){
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: item.getLatLng(),
        map: mGmap._map,
        draggable: false,
        icon: getPointIcon(item)
    });

    //infowindow
    if(item.infoWindow == null){
        item.infoWindow=makeInfoWindow(item);
        item.infoWindow.hide();
    }

    // register marker clickevent
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        //event.stopPropagation();
        // event.cancelBubble = true;
        if(mSelectedItem!=null){
            if(mSelectedItem.id==item.id){
                if(mSelectedItem.infoWindow.isShow()){
                    mSelectedItem.infoWindow.hide();
                    console.log("hide");
                }else{
                    mSelectedItem.infoWindow.show();
                    console.log("show");
                }
                refreshMap();
                window.gsMapNative.onMarkerClicked(mSelectedItem.infoWindow.isShow(),item.id,item.name,item.isMainPoi,item.poiType,item.mapType,item.inChina);
                return;
            }else{ 
                mSelectedItem.infoWindow.hide();
                mSelectedItem.infoWindow=null;
                mSelectedItem=null;
            }
        }

        console.log("create new !");
        mSelectedItem=item;
        mSelectedItem.infoWindow=makeInfoWindow(item);
        mSelectedItem.infoWindow.show();
        refreshMap();
        window.gsMapNative.onMarkerClicked(mSelectedItem.infoWindow.isShow(),item.id,item.name,item.isMainPoi,item.poiType,item.mapType,item.inChina);

        return true;
    });
    return marker;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into this before and fixed this issue by using the markerOption infoWindowIndex.  So put all of your 20 infowindows in an global array list and for each marker you specify the infowindow by specifying the index like this,

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: item.getLatLng(),
        map: mGmap._map,
        draggable: false,
        icon: getPointIcon(item),
        infoWindowIndex : index    //* <- make sure this index points to the correct info window
    });
```

in your listner function, you use the this.infoWindowIndex from the marker object to index into your infoWindo object

Comment: I may need to show you use the infoWindowIndex in your listner function, see an updated answer

Comment: Thank you for your help !
Your answer I am not clear 。
But I find another way:
I used new google.maps.Marker to create marker before,
<pre><code>
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: item.getLatLng(),
        map: mGmap._map,
        draggable: false,
        icon: getPointIcon(item),
        infoWindowIndex : index    //* <- make sure this index points to the correct info window
    });
</code></pre>

Comment: and when I use this 
var marker= new USGSOverlay(getPointView(item),item.getLatLng(),{x:-21,y:-58},'infobox',item.id);
</code></pre>

and then the clicked event is right!
I think the marker and infowindow is on same root object now,

 I will research your answer, after add infoWindowIndex and then ?
the object mSelectedItem is a global infowindow item 。 all markers use one infowindow .